# updating a fragment from activity during runtime, view variable not global

Tags: java, android, variables, android-fragments, textview

I have a tab page with 3 fragments. I have a spinner on the page. When a user selects a value from the spinner, the 3 fragments are updated with mysql data. I am having a problem with the OnCreateView, I am inflating the layout, and returning the view, but after returned to the mainactivity, the "global" view variable is cleared and when I try to update the textboxes, I get a NPE due to the view variable being null.

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {

public TabFragment1() {

    // Required empty public constructor
}

View loadInflatedView;
TextView txtLoadNumber,txtAddlStops;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    loadInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    return loadInflatedView;
}

public void updateFragment1(Integer LoadNumber, Integer AddlStops){


    txtLoadNumber = (TextView) loadInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLoadNumber);
    txtAddlStops = (TextView) loadInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddlStops);

    //Log.d(TAG, "Update Dashboard Location");
    txtLoadNumber.setText(LoadNumber);
    txtAddlStops.setText(AddlStops);
}
```

and my activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loads_tabbed);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Load"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Shipper"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Consignee"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new com.jrs.loadmanager.PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

...

//this method will execute when we pic an item from the spinner
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

```
    final Integer LoadNumber = parseInt( parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

    Cursor res = myDb.getLoadData(LoadNumber);
    ShortcutBadger.removeCount(getApplicationContext());
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (res.moveToFirst()) {

        Integer txtLoad = parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Config.TAG_LOADNUMBER)));
        Integer txtStop = parseInt(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Config.TAG_ADDSTOPS)));
        TabFragment1 FragVar = new TabFragment1();
        FragVar.updateFragment1(txtLoad,txtStop);
```

loadInflatedView is set when the OnCreateView is executed, but is null when I try to call loadInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLoadNumber);

I have searched and searched and cannot find a solution as to why this variable is clearing.

here is fatal error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jrs.loadmanager, PID: 11045
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at com.jrs.loadmanager.TabFragment1.updateFragment1(TabFragment1.java:54)
at com.jrs.loadmanager.LoadsActivity.onItemSelected(LoadsActivity.java:426)
at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:924)
at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:913)
at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(AdapterView.java)
at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) will do the trick for you

 
Register `LocalBroadcastManager` into you `fragment`

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get data from intent and update
  }
};
```

Register `mMessageReceiver` in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  // Register to receive data.
  // with actions named "my-event".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("my-event"));
}
```

Write the code below to update data from activity to fragment, This is to be written in Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my-event");
// You can also include some extra data.
intent.putExtra("data", "my data");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Do not forget to unregister the `BroadcastReceiver` on `OnDestory()` methos

Comment: I am unclear about second section. Is that OnCreate of Fragment or Activity?

Comment: No. In the one, in which you want to get an event. It means you are registering receiver to get event. In your case you are willing to update data of fragment from activity, so you have to register your receiver in `Fragment` and you will be sending broadcast from `activity`.

Comment: after much fiddling around, I finally got this to work. It seems to be just what I was searching for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your fragment has been destroyed. As the memory manager already had destroyed your fragment. So the solution could be

1.) You can add a fragment instead of replacing it.
Like -

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.Main, homeFragment, "Home");
```

2.) You can save fragment instance in

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("tag", TAG);
}
```

and restore it from

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    someVarB = savedInstanceState.getString("tag");
}
```

Just make sure you've provided a tag to your view in the xml layout.

3.) If you are using a View Pager along with tab layout the you could try this.

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

4.) If you are using ViewPager then try this one

```
ViewPager pager = /* get my ViewPager */;
```

assume this actually has stuff in it

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

pager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
public int getCount() {
    return titles.size();
}

public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setTitle(titles.get(position));
    return fragment;
}

public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
    MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment)item;
    String title = fragment.getTitle();
    int position = titles.indexOf(title);

    if (position >= 0) {
        return position;
    } else {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

});

and you have to put this in the main activity or where your tab layout and view pager is.

Comment: I'm a little new yet, could you tell me where to put these statements?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the issue persists because of the manual instantiation you've performed at the line 
`TabFragment1 FragVar = new TabFragment1();`

A little on that, the fragment objects are created and returned within the `FragmentPagerAdapter` and are then managed by the latter which is said to handle memory well.

So when you're recreating the `TabFragment1` object manually inside `onItemSelected()`, the `onCreateView()` of your `TabFragment1` **isn't fired** and thus the corresponding fragment view is not inflated.

At the same time you're trying to manipulate a `TextView` object (for instance) which hasn't been created as yet!

That's exactly why I guess you're getting a NPE.

And the probable solution on a very short note would be to use the `Bundle` class to add and receive extras, maybe. I guess that should work! Maybe someone else could add to it. :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried to leave out that statement, and change the next line to TabFragment1.updateFragment1(txtLoad,txtStop);. but then I get a "non static method cannot be called from static content" error.

Comment: You can't call updateFragment1() like that because it's a non-static method by definition. Handle the text views inside the onCreateView() using the Bundle class to get the extras. That's how I do it!